# What is the best practices for consolidating the DB record and send to frontend?

Tags: java, html, mysql, jsp, consolidation

I have a following scenario and would like to seek for advices/recommendation about the best solution to implement it.

Assuming I have following data in the DB:

| OrderID | CustomerID | OrderDate | Prices |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | CustomerA | 15-Jan-2022 | 30 |
| 2 | CustomerA | 15-Jan-2022 | 20 |
| 3 | CustomerB | 15-Jan-2022 | 13 |
| 1 | CustomerB | 16-Jan-2022 | 15 |

And would like to display following table on webpage:

| CustomerID | OrderDate | TotalPrices | Breakdown |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| CustomerA | 15-Jan-2022 | 50 | Click me |
| CustomerB | 15-Jan-2022 | 13 | Click me |
| CustomerB | 16-Jan-2022 | 15 | Click me |

When user click on the "Click me" for customerA on 15-Jan-2022, it will shows following:

| OrderID | CustomerID | OrderDate | Prices |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | CustomerA | 15-Jan-2022 | 30 |
| 2 | CustomerA | 15-Jan-2022 | 20 |

The current possible solutions in my mind are following:

1. User SQL consolidate to DB -> Return the summary table to Java API -> Send the summary table to Frontend -> When user click on the "Click Me" button, will have another SQL call to retrieve the breakdown records.
2. Retrieve the DB records -> Consolidate in Java API -> Send the summary table and breakdowns to frontend.

Feel free to suggest for more ideas on this, thanks!

Comment: Why wouldn't you just calculate those on the fly? You need two queries, one to return the overview results and one for the "click me" logic.

Comment: It's usually best to do data aggregation like this on the database rather than in Java whenever possible.

Comment: Hi @Kayaman, thanks for your reply, currently I'm using two queries for the overview and the breakdowns. Should I pass the breakdowns result together when retrieving the overview result? Or I should wait user click on the "Click Me" and then we only execute the second query to retrieve the breakdowns?

Comment: Hi @QuentinC, Thanks for your reply. Now I'm doing the data aggregation on the database level. I think it is quite efficient to aggregate on database if there is a lot of records included. :D

Comment: Why wouldn't you wait for the user to click on "click me"? What if the data changes? Are you going to return stale data?

Comment: I think it is quite efficient to aggregate on database if
there is a lot of records included. ==> If you find it slow, you can store the total for the whole order when you create/update it. Caching data can be interesting as soon as you read a lot more frequently than you update it.